# error: error parsing db.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 19: did not find expected '-' indicator

Tags: kubernetes, yaml

kubectl apply -f db.yaml
error: error parsing db.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 19: did not find expected '-' indicator
could you please give me a hint about what's wrong in the YAML file?

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
    name: my-db
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-db
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-db
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: app
          image: postgres:my-postgres
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5432
         deployment.spec.template.spec.containers.env:
        - name: POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD
          value: trust
```

Answer (score 0):

the `deployment.spec.template.spec.containers.env` is the the path in the manifest (try following the names `deployment` -> `spec` -> ... ; you can see that in the manifest). so instead of using that, you should just simply use `env` . The correct manifest is below

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
    name: my-db
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-db
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-db
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: app
          image: postgres:my-postgres
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5432
          env:
          - name: POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD
            value: trust
```

Comment: also if you are working in production environment and you are not sure the manifest is correctly written, try running ```kubectl apply -f <name_of_manifest> --dry-run=client```.